# Running more than 4 jobs in parallel with CircleCI

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

If I have a `.circleci/config.yml` file like so:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build-node8:
    docker:
      - image: oresoftware/lmx-circleci:8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./scripts/circleci/run.sh
  build-node9:
    docker:
      - image: oresoftware/lmx-circleci:9
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./scripts/circleci/run.sh
  build-node10:
    docker:
      - image: oresoftware/lmx-circleci:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./scripts/circleci/run.sh
  build-node11:
    docker:
      - image: oresoftware/lmx-circleci:11
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./scripts/circleci/run.sh
  build-node12:
    docker:
      - image: oresoftware/lmx-circleci:12
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./scripts/circleci/run.sh
```

there are 5 jobs listed here, but when the builds start, only 4 jobs run in parallel. Is there a way to run more than 4 jobs in parallel is there a hard limit there?

My guess is that under workflows, I can change the parallelism level?

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_nodejs:
    parallelism: 5
    jobs:
      - build-node8
      - build-node9
      - build-node10
      - build-node11
      - build-node12
```

perhaps this requires a paid account tho?

Comment: if you look at the docs https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/  there is no 'parallelism" option for workflows, only for each job, and I am not sure what that means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

CircleCi lets you run as many jobs in parallel as you want, as long as your payment plan has enough containers to serve each job.

I suspect that your plan only has 4 containers. You can check to see how many containers you have in the settings tab in CircleCi

In the below example I have a total of 2 containers available: 1 paid + 1 free. So right now at max I can only run 2 jobs in parallel. I can pay an extra $50 per month per container to add additional containers thoughs.
[image]

**Additional Details:**

This article gives a great overview of how to configure circle ci jobs to run in parallel (and it actually has an example where 5 jobs run in parallel). https://circleci.com/blog/decrease-your-build-times-by-running-jobs-in-parallel-with-workflows/

Regarding the config file code snippet you pasted in your question - It looks fine (Tho you don't need the *parallelism: 5 flag*, since circle will use all available plan capacity automatically)

Can you please check to see how many containers are in your plan and then report back?

FYI - CircleCi container and concurrent job plan info:
https://circleci.com/pricing/